# Full Width Bar partially filled with solid color CSS

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a bar that goes across the footer of the screen that is 80% filled with solid white, and 20% transparent where 2 social media icons are going to go.

However, my attempts at creating a bar at 100% and then putting two elements in it at 80% and 20% fail continuously. The two elements are floated:left and white-space is set to nowrap.

I made an attempt at doing display:inline-block; but that ended up pushing one of the elements in the bar about 10px down.

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this so that it'll stay a constant size until the page shrinks to a certain size and then it finally wraps? Currently the only way it stays as it's supposed to is when the width of the browser is 1,100 px wide. If you go under that, one of the social media icons gets buried under the right side of the screen (which ... shouldn't happen but... it is)

```css
    footer .logo-container .logo {
      float: right;
    }
    footer .contact-container .white-bar {
      background: #fff;
    }
    footer div.contact-info {
      float: left;
      width: 85%;
    }
    footer div.social-media {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    footer div.social-media ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    footer div.social-media ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-info white-bar">
      Phone Here | Address Here
    </div>
    <div class="social-media">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/68x40" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/71x40" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block`. The separation you're referring to happen when `inline-block` elements create space between one another. You can fix this issue by applying a `margin-right` of `-4px` to the elements.

See Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Ln6vryjL/